# Magento default all products page

Tags: magento2, product

Is there any page in Magento 2 which lists all the products present on the website by default or is there some page for the default root category which shows the default category products.

ex. if I have test category then Magento create the link http://yourwebsiteurl.com/test.html like that is there any URL for default root category in Magento

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento 2 catalog product list widget. You can set conditions as per requirement there and add it in required or all pages.

Reference: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/featured-products-in-magento-2-with-catalog-products-list-widget/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't want to list all products on any page, I am looking for the default page where Magento list them. ex. if I have test category then Magento create the link http://yourwebsiteurl.com/test.html like that is there any URL for default root category in Magento